# Read the content of the web page with content scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am new to the extension development so I am making a chrome extension which gets the content of the web page.
It is working but the main problem is i have to reload the page every time to get the data and also the extension.
Can you guys help me how to fix this?

```
myscript.js
```

```js
var c;
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port){
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(res){
    
var myurl;
  myurl=url goes here; 
  myurl+=params;
      c = res.prd; ///using the response from the content script for further use
      myurl+=c;
      alert(myurl);
      var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url":myurl,
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json"
  }
}
      
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
  var a = document.getElementById('result');
  a.innerHTML = "hellow there";

});  //ajax
  }); //onmsg
}); //oncnt
```

This above code listens the response from the web page and then the `myurl` variable is for another ajax call and that is for processing the response that came from the content script.
But the thing is i have to reload the page every time from which my content script is reading the data from.
Can you help me..

this is my manifest file

```js
{
 "manifest_version" : 2 ,
 "name" : "my",
 "version" : "1.0",
 "browser_action":
 {
  "default_popup" : "abc.html"
 },
 "content_scripts": [
     {
        "matches": ["https://www.amazon.in/*","https://www.flipkart.com/*"],
        "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.js","mycontentscript.js"]
     }
    ],
 /*"background" :{
  "scripts" : ["background.js"]
 }, */
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://*/ default-src 'self'  "
}
```

see the thing,, is i am trying to read the DOM contents of the amazon or flipkart like title of the product and etc.
But the problem is i have to reload the page every single time, to get the data..
So is there anyway i dont have to reload the page again and again to do the same..?

Comment: post your code.

Comment: see my code for the same

Comment: Both sites are AJAX-driven so they only update a portion of the page on navigation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954).

Comment: As i am new to this.. i couldn't understand the link you provided.

Comment: Can you provide more clarification?